# How to keep the state of each page when using PageTransitionSwitcher?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to add the [animation](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/master/packages/animations) library to my project,  but I am having problems.
The previous code is like this

```
  Widget _buildScaffold(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: PageView.builder(itemBuilder: (context,index)=>_pageList[index]),
  extendBody: true,
  bottomNavigationBar: Opacity(
    opacity: 0.98,
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            this.index = index;
          });
          // _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
        },
        items: _bottomList),
  ),
);
```

}
When I changed `PageView.builder` to `PageTransitionSwitcher`, according to the example, the value of child is `_pageList[index]`, the animation is available, and the state is lost when switching pages. When I try to use `PageView` as a child, the state can be set `KeepAlive` is retained, but the animation disappears (because it is judged to be the same widget)

```
  Widget _buildScaffold(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: PageTransitionSwitcher(
    transitionBuilder: (
      Widget child,
      Animation<double> primaryAnimation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
    ) {
      return FadeThroughTransition(
        animation: primaryAnimation,
        secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
        child: child,
      );
    },
    child: PageView.builder(itemBuilder: (_,index)=>_pageList[index]),
  ),
  extendBody: true,
  bottomNavigationBar: Opacity(
    opacity: 0.98,
    child: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            this.index = index;
          });
          // _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text(I18n.of(context).home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                CustomIcons.leaderboard,
              ),
              title: Text(I18n.of(context).rank)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              title: Text(I18n.of(context).quick_view)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              title: Text(I18n.of(context).search)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              title: Text(I18n.of(context).setting)),
        ]),
  ),
);
```

}

So, is there a way to preserve both the animation and the state of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.

In your stateful widget, if you are showing a list of items in your page, you can add static variable in front of the list you wanna preserve so that it wont re fetched upon switching pages.

If you are currently using a FutureBuilder, i think you have to change to this instead because you need a static list to refer to.

```
  static List<YourObject> yourList = new List();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //some async task to fetch data and populate yourList
    fetchData();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(yourList.length == 0){
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }else{
      return ListView.builder(){
        itemCount: yourList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          ...yourcodehere
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is extremely simple.
Adding the following to my `ListView` helped for me.

```
key: PageStorageKey<String>('customKeyName'),
```

I found the solution after randomly finding an article about `GlobalKey()` and that it can be used to keep/restore a widgets state.

Comment: Adding the key how could you have access to the state? 
I'm trying to refresh one of the pages programmatically.
Thanks